# How to check file content using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to see content of the file that is posted from the client i am using `fs` module so with below code contents is coming undefined , Any idea what is missing in below code ?

I have `file` printed in server side to make sure i am gettign the data.

server.js

```
var data = new multiparty.Form();
var fs = require('fs');

export function create(req, res) {
    data.parse(req, function(err,files) {
        var file = files.file;
        console.log(file);
        fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
            console.log('content',contents);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Did you check the err? Are you sure it's UTF8?

Comment: the file contains xml

Comment: @hussain — that doesn't answer either of Kwakwak's questions.

Comment: i checked err i do not see any server side.

Comment: and yes it is utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem might be the signature of the callback you are supplying to `data.parse` (you are missing the `fields` argument).
Check it yourself by looking to the examples on [multiparty docs](https://github.com/expressjs/node-multiparty)

```
var data = new multiparty.Form();
var fs = require('fs');

export function create(req, res) {
    data.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        var file = files.file;
        console.log(file);
        fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
            console.log('content',contents);
        });
    });
};
```